# Couldn't load plugin MAPIR_Processing due to error when calling classFactory() method?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

How to fix "Couldn't load plugin MAPIR_Processing due to an error when calling its classFactory() method"?

```
ImportError: No module named hid


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 333, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/admins/.qgis2/python/plugins\MAPIR_Processing\__init__.py", line 34, in classFactory
    from .MAPIR_Processing import MAPIR_Processing
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/admins/.qgis2/python/plugins\MAPIR_Processing\MAPIR_Processing.py", line 29, in 
    from MAPIR_Processing_dockwidget import MAPIR_ProcessingDockWidget
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/admins/.qgis2/python/plugins\MAPIR_Processing\MAPIR_Processing_dockwidget.py", line 39, in 
    import hid
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named hid


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.4 Las Palmas, 59c1d21 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/admins/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/admins/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/admins/.qgis2//python
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

the error is telling you you're missing a [python library called hid](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hid) which allows access to USB and Bluetooth devices.

I don't see it being bundled with the plugin, and it looks like it's not a "pure python" library, it needs the [hidapi library](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/) .. according to that first link, the author of the python hid library hasn't tried installing/compiling this on Windows. But the hidapi site does suggest it can be compiled on Windows, Mac and Linux.

I don't see it on [the list of unofficial windows binaries for python](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) either.

I suspect you may be out of luck using this plugin on Windows, unless you work out how to compile hidapi in Windows, and then use pip to install hid  :(